# Keep space for arrays/buffers for repeated use

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm using large arrays (many MB per array) but at any one time there is only one array - one gets disposed and another created to take its place. They are not of equal length, but the length does have an upper bound.

Instead of having a new array allocated every time, is there a way to allocate space for the largest array possible (which I can find out) and use whatever length of that needed to create every new array. I can't use the exact same array and use a variable for the length, because I need to feed the array on to other methods which I do not control, which need to be exactly the length of the data contained in them (which is not constant). I remember reading about some class that can do that and we ask it for a buffer and then return it to the class.

Comment: Where is the "creating a new one *every time*" coming into it? Could you not instead move the scope on to a singleton, such as the `App`?

Comment: @RowlandShaw As I wrote `I can't use the exact same array because its size is not always constant`.

Comment: So if it's not always constant, it must contain different data, at which point you're having to persist/depersist the data anyway, so what are you hoping to achieve? It's impossible to suggest improvements to code we can't see (So we've no knowledge of the heuristics of the size of the array, or whether keeping a cache is practical)

Comment: @RowlandShaw As i wrote `But I can assume some maximum size` - I want to keep one "array" of that size, and use whatever needed of that.

Comment: So why not use an array with a hard coded length in that case? It's not clear what's not working with the options in the language/framework already or what you've tried (and on that basis I could understand why others may have chosen to flag this question as "...not showing any research effort; or being unclear")

Comment: @RowlandShaw Thanks. Edited now. I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own memory manager to create a newest array when the one you have is too small or return the previously allocated one.

You can also use an [InMemoryRandomAccessStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) to store your data. This stream will resize itself to hold the data you have to store.
Using [DataWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.aspx) or [DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.aspx), you can then easily insert/read data to/from the stream.

To get a input or output stream from the InMemoryRandomAccessStream, you can use : [GttInputStreamAt(0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.getinputstreamat.aspx) or [GetOutputStreamAt(0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.getoutputstreamat.aspx)